# Split data-frames into multiple, with overlap rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A data-frame that needs to be split it into multiple data-frames. Every 6 rows (top down) to become a new data-frame.

Below lines work fine, as screenshots.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': ["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a10","a11","a12","a13","a14","a15","a16","a17","a18","a19","a20","a21","a22"], 
'Unit_Weight': [178,153,193,195,214,157,205,212,219,166,217,186,170,207,204,201,179,215,213,170,217,199]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

size = 6      # 6 rows in a new data-frame
list_of_dfs = [df.loc[i:i+size-1,:] for i in range(0, len(df),size)]

for l_d in list_of_dfs:
    print l_d
```

Now I want to do it from bottom up, and since the df_2, it includes the last 2 rows of  the previous data-frame.

What's the right way to make it happened in Python? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me:-

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': ["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a10","a11","a12","a13","a14","a15","a16","a17","a18","a19","a20","a21","a22"], 
'Unit_Weight': [178,153,193,195,214,157,205,212,219,166,217,186,170,207,204,201,179,215,213,170,217,199]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


size = 6      # 6 rows in a new data-frame
list_of_dfs = [df.loc[i:i+size-1,:] for i in range(0, len(df),size-2) if i <len(df)-2]

for l_d in list_of_dfs:
    print (l_d)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would work forward but just count the dataframe numbers backwards.

```
df_num = 5
li_dicts = {}

for x in range(0,17,4):
    y = x + 6
    df_temp = df.iloc[x:y,:]
    li_dicts[("df_" + str(df_num))] = df_temp
    df_num -= 1

li_dicts['df_5']

   ID  Unit_Weight
0  a1          178
1  a2          153
2  a3          193
3  a4          195
4  a5          214
5  a6          157
```

Comment: I like @Udit Hari Vashisht answer better!